# Passing value from unchecked checkbox

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox

I have a following code in PHP and HTML

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="tableRow1[<?php $count; ?>]["InvoiceNum"]" id="InvoiceNum" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['InvoiceNum'];?>" ></input> </td>
            <td><input name="tableRow1[<?php $count; ?>]["StoreName"]" id="StoreName" type= "text" value="<?php echo $row['StoreName'];?>" ></input></td>
            <td><input name="tableRow1[<?php $count; ?>]["Driver"]" id="Driver" type= "checkbox" value= "<?php echo $login_session;?>" ></input></td>
        </tr>
        <?php $count++;
                }
        ?>
    </tbody>
        </table>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

I have an array and it gets value from 2 column of a database and 1 user input from checkbox. And I am trying to pass value from unchecked checkbox, but I haven't been successful so far. I tried to use `<hidden>` too but still no success yet.

If someone can help me pass both checked and unchecked value from checkbox I shall be highly grateful.

Comment: what are you trying?, check or uncheck the checkbox? because that variable that are you passing through the value doesn't have an index like the other ones

Comment: Aside: You are not echoing your count.

Comment: If the checkbox is not ticked, no attribute pair is sent for that checkbox element, dump the superglobals to see what has been submitted.  You can use isset as a test.

Answer (score 0):

HTML checkboxes don't work that way. You need to pass a value that's meaningful to you, like "1", or "On", or "active", and to make it checked, add the `checked` attribute, like this:

`<input name="Name" id="ID" type="checkbox" value= "1" checked>`

In your case, you need to add code that will add the `checked`attribute based on your data, like this, for example:

```
<input name="tableRow1[<?php $count; ?>]["Driver"]" 
    id="Driver" 
    type= "checkbox" 
    value="1" 
    <?php 
      echo "checked" ? !empty($login_session) : "";
    ?>"
>
```

This will make it checked when `$login_session` has some value (when it's not empty).